# Unary operator precedence in yacc

Tags: yacc

I'm getting a strange error in my YACC parser. It's a simple boolean algebra expression evaluator.

Everything works except the following type of situation:

```
> True and False
False
> (True and False)
False
> not (True and False)     <--- interpreted as (not True and False)
False
```

example.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *err);

%}

%token NEWLINE EQUIV IMPL OR AND NOT CONST

%union {
    bool value;
}

%type <value> CONST value not and or impl equiv expr

%%

program:
    |
    program expr NEWLINE
    ;

expr:
    equiv               { printf("%s\n", $1?"True":"False"); }             
    ;

equiv:
    impl                { $$ = $1; }                   
    |
    equiv EQUIV impl    { $$ = $1 == $3; }     
    ;

impl:
    or              { $$ = $1; }               
    |
    impl IMPL or    { $$ = !$1 || $3; }
    ;

or:
    and             { $$ = $1; }   
    |
    or OR and       { $$ = $1 || $3; } 
    ;

and:
    not             { $$ = $1; }           
    |
    and AND not     { $$ = $1 && $3; }     
    ;

not:
    value           { $$ = $1; }           
    |
    NOT not         { $$ = !$2; }
    ;

value:
    CONST           { $$ = $1; }           
    |
    '(' expr ')'    { $$ = $2; }
    ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
}

int main() {
    yyparse();
}
```

example.l:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
extern "C" int yywrap();
%}

%%

True                yylval.value = true; return CONST;
False               yylval.value = false; return CONST;

"<=>"               return EQUIV;
=>                  return IMPL;
or                  return OR;
and                 return AND;
not                 return NOT;

[ \t]               ;
\n                  return NEWLINE;
.                   ;

%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

Compiled with

```
bison -dy example.y
flex -l example.l
g++ y.tab.c lex.yy.c
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve], what you posted is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @sepp2k Uploaded a reproducible example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only rule in your lexer that matches parentheses is the `.` rule, which does not return anything (or give any indication that a character has been ignored, which is a bad idea exactly because it makes problems like this so much easier to miss). Thus the parentheses in your input are completely ignored, the `'('` and `')'` in your grammar can never be matched and the input the parser sees is simply `not True and False`.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I forgot to put `return *yytext` there. I was only searching for errors in the parser myself to be honest.